# Play Media (.mp4) on the receiver app

Tags: google-cast

I am trying to play/push a MP4 to my receiver app on my whitelisted device.

I am able to launch my receiver app (an web page with a video tag).

Once I launch my receiver app, then from my Sender app (another web page) I do this:

```
new MediaLoadRequest(url);
cast_api.loadMedia(activityId, mediaRequest, callback);
```

My receiver looks like this:

```
initReceiver = function(){

_remoteMedia.setMediaElement(videoSurface);

_remoteMedia.onOpen = mediaOnOpen;

_remoteMedia.onLoad = mediaOnLoad;       
_remoteMedia.onLoadMetadataError = mediaMetaDataError;
_remoteMedia.onMetadataLoaded = mediaMetaDataLoaded;

_receiver.start();
mediaOnLoad = function (channel, message){
    _remoteMedia.load(channel, message);
    _remoteMedia.sendSuccessResponse(channel,message);  

}

mediaMetaDataLoaded = function (channel, message){
    console.log("mediaMetaDataLoaded", message);
}

mediaMetaDataError = function (channel,message){
    console.log("mediaMetaDataError", message);
}

mediaOnOpen = function (event){
    console.log("mediaOnOpen", event);          
}
```

On the console output the last message I see is this, after the code hits _remoteMedia.load:

```
[ 41.321s] [cast.receiver.RemoteMedia] loading media
```

and nothing happens after that. The media is a valid URL from my DropBox...an MP4.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually can just use our [default Receiver](https://github.com/googlecast/cast-android-sample/blob/master/receiver/receiver.html) and it will play your content.  No need to provide all those extra functions.

Comment: Thanks @Les Vogel - Google DevRel That is good news. I didnt know that a default receiver is available for us to play with. I will try this out and report back. It would have been good to learn what I am doing wrong though, but this helps.

Comment: Finally I was able to get my code work too...It was a bad Mp4 from an older phone that refused to play with my reciever or the default receiver. Once I changed that, I am able to play using my receiver app too. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: I get the 404 error when the receiver tries to load a public MP4 download URL from my Dropbox. What could be the problem here?